# How to load .NET DLL remotely within new AppDomain

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain, .net-remoting

I tied to create simple program Console App C# .NET 4.0 to load DLL file remotely.
My code works as expected on load dll that on the local computer but I got problem resolve dll when trying to load remotely.
I have no idea to handle this since I can't find any code example that load dll remotely.

The error I got as following.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'http://codesanook.cloudapp.net/dll/ZupZip.Lib.I
nterfaces.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exceptio
n from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String cod
eBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntro
spection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String code
Base, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& s
tackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntros
pection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName as
semblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMar
k& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIn
trospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Ev
idence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm,
Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackM
ark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at LoadDllRemotely.Proxy.GetObject[T](String assemblyPath, String fullTypeNam
e, String[] referencedAssembliesPath) in C:\Projects\LoadDllRemotely\LoadDllRemo
tely\Program.cs:line 102

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
   at LoadDllRemotely.Program.LoadRemotely() in C:\Projects\LoadDllRemotely\Load
DllRemotely\Program.cs:line 74
   at LoadDllRemotely.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\LoadDllRemotely
\LoadDllRemotely\Program.cs:line 28
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is my implementation that load dll remotely with new AppDomain

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using ZupZip.Lib.Interfaces;

namespace LoadDllRemotely
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string ASSEMBLY_PATH =
                        @"C:\Projects\LoadDllRemotely\ZupZip.Lib\bin\Debug\ZupZip.Lib.dll";
        private const string ASSEMBLY_URL =
                        @"http://codesanook.cloudapp.net/dll/ZupZip.Lib.dll";

        private const string REFERENCED_ASSEMBLY3_URL =
                @"http://codesanook.cloudapp.net/dll/ZupZip.Lib.Interfaces.dll";

        private const string REFERENCED_ASSEMBLY2_URL =
                @"http://codesanook.cloudapp.net/dll/system.core.dll";


        private const string REFERENCED_ASSEMBLY1_URL =
                @"http://codesanook.cloudapp.net/dll/mscorlib.dll";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //LoadLocally();
            LoadRemotely();
        }

        public static void appDomain_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("domain loaded sender: {0}",
                sender.GetType().FullName);
        }


        public static void LoadLocally()
        {
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("dynamicDll");
            appDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler(appDomain_DomainUnload);
            var proxy = (Proxy)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                typeof(Proxy).Assembly.FullName,
                typeof(Proxy).FullName);

            var calculator = proxy.GetObject<IGradeCalculator>(
                ASSEMBLY_PATH,
                "ZupZip.Lib.GradeCalculator");
            var score = 80;
            Console.WriteLine("you got grad: {0} from score: {1}", calculator.GetGradeForScore(score), score);

            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);

            File.Delete(ASSEMBLY_PATH);//you can delete referece dll after remove 
        }


        public static void LoadRemotely()
        {
            //app domain setup 
            //load as byte array
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("dynamicDll");
            appDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler(appDomain_DomainUnload);

            var proxy = (Proxy)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                typeof(Proxy).Assembly.FullName,
                typeof(Proxy).FullName);

            var calculator = proxy.GetObject<IGradeCalculator>(
                ASSEMBLY_URL,
                "ZupZip.Lib.GradeCalculator",
                REFERENCED_ASSEMBLY3_URL);
            var score = 80;
            Console.WriteLine("you got grad: {0} from score: {1}", calculator.GetGradeForScore(score), score);

            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);

        }

    }

    public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public T GetObject<T>(
            string assemblyPath,
            string fullTypeName,
            params string[] referencedAssembliesPath) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                //find reference
                var assemblyToLoad = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                AssemblyName[] referencedAssemblies = assemblyToLoad.GetReferencedAssemblies();
                //foreach (var referencedAssembly in referencedAssemblies)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("referenceAssemblyName: {0}", referencedAssembly.Name);
                //    Assembly.Load(referencedAssembly.Name);
                //}
                //solve reference assembly
                foreach (var referencedAssemblyPath in referencedAssembliesPath)
                {
                    Assembly.LoadFrom(referencedAssemblyPath);
                }

                //this dll will load in new domain
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                var type = assembly.GetType(fullTypeName);
                var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I also add this source code to my open source on Bitbuckget

[enter link description here](https://bitbucket.org/theeranitp/loaddllremotely)

Comment: "I got problem resolve dll when trying to load remotely." And that problem was? Please include the full text of any error messages you got or explain the unexpected behavior. Also why are you referencing `system.core.dll` and `mscorlib.dll` remotely?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you so much for your comment I add more information that you suggest me I hope if you have time please download my project and help me solve this problem.


Thanks again.

Comment: Note that .NET Remoting is [discontinued](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/02/Core-Discontinued) in .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed
just add this configuration to App.Config to run in full trust

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and I also update this code at

https://bitbucket.org/theeranitp/loaddllremotely